# Проблема с библиотекой с GitHub

Tags: java, android

Учусь по книге "Head First Java". Пытаюсь внедрить в свое приложение ProgressWheel [Material-ish Progress](https://github.com/pnikosis/materialish-progress#usage).

Скопировал java класс в свой проект по инструкции. Автор пишет: вы можете вставить "Колесо" с помощью xml разметки или с помощью кода:

```
ProgressWheel wheel = new ProgressWheel(context);
wheel.setBarColor(Color.BLUE);
```

И вот проблема: слово context подсвечивается красным, так вот вопрос: что туда передавать или какой код писать? Не понимаю чего от меня требует компилятор (в моей книге эта штука называется компилятором)

Объясните поподробней, что это за объект, для чего ему передавать этот "context" и почему там не указан тип передаваемого параметра? И как сделать чтобы код заработал?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучше всего вставлять такие компоненты в xml разметке и потом получать ссылки так:

```
ProgressWheel wheel;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    wheel = (ProgressWheel) findViewById(R.id.progress_wheel);
}
```

Если же обязательно надо создавать на лету, то тогда:

```
ProgressWheel wheel;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    View v = findViewById(R.id.progress_wheel);
    wheel = new ProgressWheel(this);
    view.addView(wheel);
}
```

в качестве `Context` во втором случае передается `Activity`. Доступ к этому объекту нужен компонентам для получения ресурсов и другой информации о приложении

Comment: Огромное спасибо. Сразу все стало понятно!)))

Comment: Прям во всем разобрался))))))))Радуюсь сижу)))

Answer (score 4):

Капитан очевидность сообщает: Компилятор хочет от вас контекст.

Чтобы его получить используйте вместо неопределенной переменной `context`

вызов

```
 wheel = new ProgressWheel(getApplicationContext());
```

или

```
 wheel = new ProgressWheel(View.getContext());
```

Тип передаваемого параметра очевидно: `Context`

Что-то из-этого должно сработать. В кратце [context это гигансткий класс с разной полезной глобальной метаинформацией](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) о приложении.

Comment: Вау))уже не светится. Можете теперь вкратце объяснить что делает этот getContext, чтобы я понял логику?)))Что почитать, чтобы понять что такое этот "контекст"?))
Очень неловко задавать такие непрофессиональные вопросы, но все же..."

Comment: Метод getContext() возвращает объект типа Context, в котором работает данный View. Затем происходит передача его в конструктор ProgressWheel. Всё, строчка говорит сама за себя, нет никакого скрытого смысла и сложностей.

Comment: Ошибки исчезли, а колесо все равно не появляется(((

Comment: Может стоит включить его c помощью wheel.spin(), и/или указать вместо View точное имя вашего View?

Comment: И еще там в конструкторе на самом деле два параметра, нужно набор атрибутов указать еще, спарсив его из XML http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/AttributeSet.html либо вместо вызова конструктора и new использовать `ProgressWheel pw = (ProgressWheel) findViewById(R.id.pw_spinner);`

Comment: Вот черт это все для другого ProgressWheel, их там два. Печаль. Значит скорее всего нужно точно указать View либо проверить XML и использовать `progressWheel.setProgress(float value)`